# Fastest way to add rows for missing time steps?

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, data.table

I have a column in my datasets where time periods (`Time`) are integers ranging from a-b. Sometimes there might be missing time periods for any given group. I'd like to fill in those rows with `NA`. Below is example data for 1 (of several 1000) group(s).

```
structure(list(Id = c(1, 1, 1, 1), Time = c(1, 2, 4, 5), Value = c(0.568780482159894, 
-0.7207749516298, 1.24258192959273, 0.682123081696789)), .Names = c("Id", 
"Time", "Value"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")


  Id Time      Value
1  1    1  0.5687805
2  1    2 -0.7207750
3  1    4  1.2425819
4  1    5  0.6821231
```

As you can see, Time 3 is missing. Often one or more could be missing. I can solve this on my own but am afraid I wouldn't be doing this the most efficient way. My approach would be to create a function that:

Generate a sequence of time periods from `min(Time)` to `max(Time)`

Then do a `setdiff` to grab missing `Time` values.

Convert that vector to a `data.frame`

Pull unique identifier variables (`Id` and others not listed above), and add that to this data.frame.

Merge the two.

Return from function.

So the entire process would then get executed as below:

```
   # Split the data into individual data.frames by Id.
    temp_list <- dlply(original_data, .(Id)) 
    # pad each data.frame
    tlist2 <- llply(temp_list, my_pad_function)
    # collapse the list back to a data.frame
    filled_in_data <- ldply(tlist2)
```

Better way to achieve this?

Comment: I would do basically what you describe, only using `expand.grid` and then `merge` with `all = TRUE`. Not sure splitting by Id first is necessary, really.

Comment: Here is an added complication, there are numerous id variables. I only need to add `Time` and set `Value` to `NA` and pad the rest. So then it becomes `data_to_merge <- data.frame(id=unique(data$id),...)`  (which is a really long line and not portable if the structure of the data changes). Wish I could just merge missing Time, add NA and grab all the rest from the original data efficiently.

Comment: I've got it working now but could still use a general solution since this would be in a package and I dont' know what a user might submit as original data.

Comment: For ungrouped data, see also several nice answers in [How to Add zero to missing value in r](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41613710/how-to-add-zero-to-missing-value-in-r).

Answer (score 38):

Following up on comments with Ben Barnes and starting with his `mydf3` :

```
DT = as.data.table(mydf3)
setkey(DT,Id,Time)
DT[CJ(unique(Id),seq(min(Time),max(Time)))]
      Id Time        Value Id2
 [1,]  1    1 -0.262482283   2
 [2,]  1    2 -1.423935165   2
 [3,]  1    3  0.500523295   1
 [4,]  1    4 -1.912687398   1
 [5,]  1    5 -1.459766444   2
 [6,]  1    6 -0.691736451   1
 [7,]  1    7           NA  NA
 [8,]  1    8  0.001041489   2
 [9,]  1    9  0.495820559   2
[10,]  1   10 -0.673167744   1
First 10 rows of 12800 printed. 

setkey(DT,Id,Id2,Time)
DT[CJ(unique(Id),unique(Id2),seq(min(Time),max(Time)))]
      Id Id2 Time      Value
 [1,]  1   1    1         NA
 [2,]  1   1    2         NA
 [3,]  1   1    3  0.5005233
 [4,]  1   1    4 -1.9126874
 [5,]  1   1    5         NA
 [6,]  1   1    6 -0.6917365
 [7,]  1   1    7         NA
 [8,]  1   1    8         NA
 [9,]  1   1    9         NA
[10,]  1   1   10 -0.6731677
First 10 rows of 25600 printed.
```

`CJ` stands for Cross Join, see `?CJ`. The padding with `NA`s happens because `nomatch` by default is `NA`. Set `nomatch` to `0` instead to remove the no matches. If instead of padding with `NA`s the prevailing row is required, just add `roll=TRUE`. This can be more efficient than padding with `NA`s and then filling `NA`s afterwards. See the description of `roll` in `?data.table`.

```
setkey(DT,Id,Time)
DT[CJ(unique(Id),seq(min(Time),max(Time))),roll=TRUE]
      Id Time        Value Id2
 [1,]  1    1 -0.262482283   2
 [2,]  1    2 -1.423935165   2
 [3,]  1    3  0.500523295   1
 [4,]  1    4 -1.912687398   1
 [5,]  1    5 -1.459766444   2
 [6,]  1    6 -0.691736451   1
 [7,]  1    7 -0.691736451   1
 [8,]  1    8  0.001041489   2
 [9,]  1    9  0.495820559   2
[10,]  1   10 -0.673167744   1
First 10 rows of 12800 printed. 

setkey(DT,Id,Id2,Time)
DT[CJ(unique(Id),unique(Id2),seq(min(Time),max(Time))),roll=TRUE]
      Id Id2 Time      Value
 [1,]  1   1    1         NA
 [2,]  1   1    2         NA
 [3,]  1   1    3  0.5005233
 [4,]  1   1    4 -1.9126874
 [5,]  1   1    5 -1.9126874
 [6,]  1   1    6 -0.6917365
 [7,]  1   1    7 -0.6917365
 [8,]  1   1    8 -0.6917365
 [9,]  1   1    9 -0.6917365
[10,]  1   1   10 -0.6731677
First 10 rows of 25600 printed.
```

---

Instead of setting keys, you may use `on`. `CJ` also takes a `unique` argument. A small example with two 'Id':

```
d <- data.table(Id = rep(1:2, 4:3), Time = c(1, 2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4), val = 1:7)

d[CJ(Id, Time = seq(min(Time), max(Time)), unique = TRUE), on = .(Id, Time)]
#     Id Time val
# 1:   1    1   1
# 2:   1    2   2
# 3:   1    3  NA
# 4:   1    4   3
# 5:   1    5   4
# 6:   2    1  NA
# 7:   2    2   5
# 8:   2    3   6
# 9:   2    4   7
# 10:  2    5  NA
```

In this particular case, where one of the vectors in `CJ` was generated with `seq`, the result needs to be named explictly in order to match the names specified in `on`. When using bare variables in `CJ` though (like 'Id' here), they are auto-named, like in `data.table()` (from `data.table 1.12.2`).

Comment: I never fully understood the use for `roll`; how can it help me get the NA's?

Comment: @rbatt  The DataCamp data.table course explains it best with Arun and I on screen with animated graphics alongside. Chapter 3 covers joins and rolling joins. It's [here](https://www.datacamp.com/courses/data-table-data-manipulation-r-tutorial).

Comment: How would you pad with `seq(min(Time), max(Time))` by group?

Comment: @sirallen For padding with `seq()` please ask a new question. Too long for comment.

Comment: @sirallen See e.g. [Efficient way to Fill Time-Series per group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46712379/efficient-way-to-fill-time-series-per-group?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Filling missing dates by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31502591/filling-missing-dates-by-group/31502628#31502628)

Comment: @MattDowle Perhaps edit your very nice answer to also include more recent features such as `on` as an alternative to `setkey`, and the use of `unique` argument in `CJ`. Cheers

Comment: @Henrik good idea. If anybody else watching who knows about that could make the edit, would really help so I can keep going on the issue/pr list.

Comment: @MattDowle I made an edit. Hope it looks ok. Cheers.

Comment: @Henrik Looks great. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `tidyr` for this.

Use [`tidyr::complete`](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/complete.html) to fill in rows for `Time`, and by default the values are filled in with `NA`.

#### Create Data

I extended the sample data to show that it works for multiple `Id`s and even when within an `Id` the full range of `Time` is not present.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


df <- tibble(
  Id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
  Time = c(1, 2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 5),
  Value = c(0.56, -0.72, 1.24, 0.68, 1.46, 0.74, 0.99)
)

df
#> # A tibble: 7 x 3
#>      Id  Time Value
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1  0.56
#> 2     1     2 -0.72
#> 3     1     4  1.24
#> 4     1     5  0.68
#> 5     2     2  1.46
#> 6     2     3  0.74
#> 7     2     5  0.99
```

#### Fill in the missing rows

```r
df %>% complete(nesting(Id), Time = seq(min(Time), max(Time), 1L))

#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>       Id  Time Value
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1      1     1  0.56
#> 2      1     2 -0.72
#> 3      1     3    NA
#> 4      1     4  1.24
#> 5      1     5  0.68
#> 6      2     1    NA
#> 7      2     2  1.46
#> 8      2     3  0.74
#> 9      2     4    NA
#> 10     2     5  0.99
```

Comment: I found this particular solution the easiest to work with to answer the same question as above, especially when using tidyverse for data manipulation.

Answer (score 5):

*Please see Matthew Dowle's answer (by now, hopefully above).*

Here's something that uses the `data.table` package, and it may help when there is more than one ID variable. It may also be faster than `merge`, depending on how you want your results. I'd be interested in benchmarking and/or suggested improvements.

First, create some more demanding data with two ID variables

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(1)

mydf3<-data.frame(Id=sample(1:100,10000,replace=TRUE),
  Value=rnorm(10000))
mydf3<-mydf3[order(mydf3$Id),]

mydf3$Time<-unlist(by(mydf3,mydf3$Id,
  function(x)sample(1:(nrow(x)+3),nrow(x)),simplify=TRUE))

mydf3$Id2<-sample(1:2,nrow(mydf3),replace=TRUE)
```

Create a function (This has been **EDITED** - see history)

```
padFun<-function(data,idvars,timevar){
# Coerce ID variables to character
  data[,idvars]<-lapply(data[,idvars,drop=FALSE],as.character)
# Create global ID variable of all individual ID vars pasted together
  globalID<-Reduce(function(...)paste(...,sep="SOMETHINGWACKY"),
    data[,idvars,drop=FALSE])
# Create data.frame of all possible combinations of globalIDs and times
  allTimes<-expand.grid(globalID=unique(globalID),
    allTime=min(data[,timevar]):max(data[,timevar]),
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
# Get the original ID variables back
  allTimes2<-data.frame(allTimes$allTime,do.call(rbind,
    strsplit(allTimes$globalID,"SOMETHINGWACKY")),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
# Convert combinations data.frame to data.table with idvars and timevar as key
  allTimesDT<-data.table(allTimes2)
  setnames(allTimesDT,1:ncol(allTimesDT),c(timevar,idvars))
  setkeyv(allTimesDT,c(idvars,timevar))
# Convert data to data.table with same variables as key
  dataDT<-data.table(data,key=c(idvars,timevar))
# Join the two data.tables to create padding
  res<-dataDT[allTimesDT]
  return(res)
}
```

Use the function

```
(padded2<-padFun(data=mydf3,idvars=c("Id"),timevar="Time"))

#       Id Time        Value Id2
#  [1,]  1    1 -0.262482283   2
#  [2,]  1    2 -1.423935165   2
#  [3,]  1    3  0.500523295   1
#  [4,]  1    4 -1.912687398   1
#  [5,]  1    5 -1.459766444   2
#  [6,]  1    6 -0.691736451   1
#  [7,]  1    7           NA  NA
#  [8,]  1    8  0.001041489   2
#  [9,]  1    9  0.495820559   2
# [10,]  1   10 -0.673167744   1
# First 10 rows of 12800 printed.

(padded<-padFun(data=mydf3,idvars=c("Id","Id2"),timevar="Time"))

#      Id Id2 Time      Value
#  [1,]  1   1    1         NA
#  [2,]  1   1    2         NA
#  [3,]  1   1    3  0.5005233
#  [4,]  1   1    4 -1.9126874
#  [5,]  1   1    5         NA
#  [6,]  1   1    6 -0.6917365
#  [7,]  1   1    7         NA
#  [8,]  1   1    8         NA
#  [9,]  1   1    9         NA
# [10,]  1   1   10 -0.6731677
# First 10 rows of 25600 printed.
```

The edited function splits the globalID into its component parts in the combination data.frame, before merging with the original data. This should (I think) be better.

Comment: Right package, but far too complex. Did you somehow miss `roll=TRUE` which is specifically for this? Keep the data irregular in the table, then join the regular time series to it. See the 3rd section of the "intro to data.table" vignette and the example in `?data.table` using `roll=TRUE`. It's one of the main features of the package.

Comment: @MatthewDowle, You know your own functions much better than I, and any suggestions for improvement are very welcome. Since the OP wanted to "pad" non-ID and non-time variables with `NA` for each missing `Time`, I thought using `roll=TRUE` would be the wrong approach, since this would "pad" with the previous value, right? It seems that most of the complexity in the function has to do with considering multiple ID variables, not with the join part, which is very nicely achievable with `data.table`.

Answer (score 0):

My general approach is to use `freqTable <- as.data.frame(table(idvar1, idvar2, idvarN))` then pull out the rows where `Freq==0`, pad as necessary and then stack back onto the original data.