# How to use an unknown number of key columns in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to do the same as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438969/fastest-way-to-add-rows-for-missing-values-in-a-data-frame), i.e. adding missing rows to a data.table. The only additional difficulty I'm facing is that I want the number of key columns, i.e. those rows that are used for the self-join, to be flexible.

Here is a small example that basically repeats what is done in the link mentioned above:

```
df <- data.frame(fundID   = rep(letters[1:4], each=6),
                 cfType   = rep(c("D", "D", "T", "T", "R", "R"), times=4),
                 variable = rep(c(1,3), times=12),
                 value    = 1:24)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
idCols <- c("fundID", "cfType")
setkeyv(DT, c(idCols, "variable"))
DT[CJ(unique(df$fundID), unique(df$cfType), seq(from=min(variable), to=max(variable))), nomatch=NA]
```

What bothers me is the last line. I want `idCols` to be flexible (for instance if I use it within a function), so I don't want to type `unique(df$fundID), unique(df$cfType)` manually. However, I just don't find any workaround for this. All my attempts to automatically split the subset of `df` into vectors, as needed by `CJ`, fail with the error message *Error in setkeyv(x, cols, verbose = verbose) : Column 'V1' is type 'list' which is not (currently) allowed as a key column type.*

```
CJ(sapply(df[, idCols], unique))
CJ(unique(df[, idCols]))
CJ(as.vector(unique(df[, idCols])))
CJ(unique(DT[, idCols, with=FALSE]))
```

I also tried building the expression myself:

```
str <- ""
for (i in idCols) {
  str <- paste0(str, "unique(df$", i, "), ")
}
str <- paste0(str, "seq(from=min(variable), to=max(variable))")
str
[1] "unique(df$fundID), unique(df$cfType), seq(from=min(variable), to=max(variable))"
```

But then I don't know how to use `str`. This all fails:

```
CJ(eval(str))
CJ(substitute(str))
CJ(call(str))
```

Does anyone know a good workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used the data.table package, so forgive me if I miss the mark here, but I think I've got it.  There's a lot going on here. Start by reading up on `do.call`, which allows you to evaluate any function in a sort of non-traditional manner where arguments are specified by a supplied list (where each element is in the list is positionally matched to the function arguments unless explicitly named).  Also notice that I had to specify `min(df$variable)` instead of just `min(variable)`.  Read [Hadley's page on scoping](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Evaluation) to get an idea of the issue here.

```
CJargs <- lapply(df[, idCols], unique)
names(CJargs) <- NULL
CJargs[[length(CJargs) +1]] <- seq(from=min(df$variable), to=max(df$variable))
DT[do.call("CJ", CJargs),nomatch=NA]
```

Comment: That does indeed work, so thank you very much. I guess I have to read that Hadley page again. I stumbled across it a couple of times, but for me it remains try and error ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Michael's answer is great. `do.call` is indeed needed to call `CJ` flexibly in that way, afaik.

To clear up on the expression building approach and starting with your code, but removing the `df$` parts (not needed and not done in the linked answer, since `i` is evaluated within the scope of `DT`) :

```
str <- "" 
for (i in idCols) { 
  str <- paste0(str, "unique(", i, "), ") 
} 
str <- paste0(str, "seq(from=min(variable), to=max(variable))") 
str 
[1] "unique(fundID), unique(cfType), seq(from=min(variable), to=max(variable))"
```

then it's :

```
expr <- parse(text=paste0("CJ(",str,")"))
DT[eval(expr),nomatch=NA]
```

or alternatively build and eval the whole query dynamically :

```
eval(parse(text=paste0("DT[CJ(",str,"),nomatch=NA")))
```

And if this is done a lot then it may be worth creating yourself a helper function :

```
E = function(...) eval(parse(text=paste0(...)))
```

to reduce it to :

```
E("DT[CJ(",str,"),nomatch=NA")
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the hints...I guess I really have to play around more with expression building, so that's a great starting point.