# How to create dynamic query in data table in R

Tags: r, data.table

**updated with example:**
I have a function as follows:

```
myfun <- function(DT, var){  
  for(i in 1:length(var)){
    s = substitute(!(is.na(x) | is.nan(x)), list(x=as.symbol(eval(var[i]))))
    DT = DT[eval(s)]
  }
  return(DT)
}
```

input:

```
> dt = data.table(id=c(1,2,3,4,5), x=c(1,2,NA,4,5), y=c(1,NA,3,4,NA))
> dt
   id  x  y
1:  1  1  1
2:  2  2 NA
3:  3 NA  3
4:  4  4  4
5:  5  5 NA
```

runs:

```
> myfun(dt, var=c("x", "y"))
   id x y
1:  1 1 1
2:  4 4 4
> myfun(dt, var=c("x"))
   id x  y
1:  1 1  1
2:  2 2 NA
3:  4 4  4
4:  5 5 NA
```

`var` is an character array of some variables in DT. The goal is to only obtain rows in DT which do not have any `NA` or `NaN` wrt to any of variables in `var`.

**I do not WANT the for loop.** I want to construct a query `s` with all the conditions and then evaluate that query for `DT`. for the first case I want:

```
s = !(is.na(x) | is.nan(x) | is.na(y) | is.nan(y))
```

and for the second case I want:

```
s = !(is.na(x) | is.nan(x))
```

How can I construct a dynamic query `s` and just run it once as an `i/where` query in the data table.

More generally how can I create dynamic `expression` based on input. Using `expression(paste())` did not help me. Then I can use `substitute`.

Comment: Maybe give us example input and its associated expected output?

Comment: @Frank: Updated with an example.

Comment: Never mind. I found it in:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677424/how-to-use-an-unknown-number-of-key-columns-in-a-data-table?rq=1

str=paste0("is.na(",var,") |", " is.nan(",var,")", collapse="|")
s = parse(text=paste("!(",str,")"))
dt[eval(s)]

Comment: You should probably move your answer to the "Your Answer" box below. Answering your own question is actually encouraged: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: OK. I have added it. need to understand more about parse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ans:

```
var = c("x","y")
str=paste0("is.na(",var,") |", " is.nan(",var,")", collapse="|")
s = parse(text=paste("!(",str,")"))
DT[eval(s)]
```

source:
[How to use an unknown number of key columns in a data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677424/how-to-use-an-unknown-number-of-key-columns-in-a-data-table?rq=1)

Comment: +1 This works as long as "s" isn't a column name. If "s" might ever be a column name in future, use ".s" instead of "s", or build the entire query (including the "DT[" bit) and eval that as a whole.

Comment: @MatthewDowle - Thanks! That is a very important point! Do you have any pointers about the detailed structure of an expression in R. There is some mention of it in the Writing R Extensions doc, but any detailed info will be appreciated.

Comment: NP. Not sure what you mean by detailed structure. `.Internal(inspect(expression(1+2+3)))` ?

Comment: In 5.11 Evaluating R expressions from C (http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Evaluating-R-expressions-from-C), it says when constructing an expression: "There are three steps: the call is constructed as a pairlist of length 3, the list is filled in, and the expression represented by the pairlist is evaluated." The example then shows the list being filled it. It is kind of vague for beginners, but the .Internal with inspect gives me some hope :) Thanks!