# Adding row for missing value in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

My question is somehow related to [Fastest way to add rows for missing values in a data.frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438969/fastest-way-to-add-rows-for-missing-values-in-a-data-frame) but a bit tougher I think. And I can't figure out how to adapt this solution to my problem.

Here is what my data.table looks like :

```
                   ida       idb         value     date
   1:               A         2          26600  2004-12-31
   2:               A         3          19600  2005-03-31
   3:               B         3          18200  2005-06-30
   4:               B         4          1230   2005-09-30
   5:               C         2          8700   2005-12-31
```

The difference is that every 'ida' has his own dates and there is at least one row where 'ida' appears with each date but not necessarily for all 'idb'. I want to insert every missing ('ida','idb') couple missing with the corresponding date and 0 as a value.

Moreover, there is no periodicity for the dates.

How would you do this ?

Desired output :

```
                   ida       idb         value     date
   1:               A         2          26600  2004-12-31
   1:               A         2            0    2005-03-31
   2:               A         3          19600  2005-03-31
   2:               A         3            0    2004-12-31
   3:               B         3          18200  2005-06-30
   4:               B         3            0    2005-09-30
   5:               B         4          1230   2005-09-30
   4:               B         4            0    2005-06-30
   6:               C         2          8700   2005-12-31
```

The order doesn't matter. Every date missing is filled with a 0 value.

Comment: So what's the desired output for this sample input?

Comment: does your example include one missing couple?

Comment: use `seq` with `range(date)`, then turn the Date vector into one column `data.table`, setkey on both DTs on `date` field, join both, fill NA with 0. If you manage to solve your problem don't forget to put the code in answer and mark as accepted.

Comment: I added the desired output, sorry about that.
@JanGorecki : I can't use seq since there is no periodicity with the date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just do the same thing as in your linked question by each `ida`:

```
setkey(dt, idb, date)

dt[, .SD[CJ(unique(idb), unique(date))], by = ida][is.na(value), value := 0][]
#   ida idb value       date
#1:   A   2 26600 2004-12-31
#2:   A   2     0 2005-03-31
#3:   A   3     0 2004-12-31
#4:   A   3 19600 2005-03-31
#5:   C   2  8700 2005-12-31
#6:   B   3 18200 2005-06-30
#7:   B   3     0 2005-09-30
#8:   B   4     0 2005-06-30
#9:   B   4  1230 2005-09-30
```