# Extend an irregular sequence and add zeros to missing values

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a sequence in 'col1' and values in 'col2':

```
col1 col2
2     0.02
5     0.12
9     0.91
13    1.13
```

I want to expand the irregular sequence in 'col1' with a regular sequence from 1 to 13. For the values in 'col1' which are missing in the original data, I want 'col2' to have the value `0` in the final output:

```
col1  col2
1     0
2     0.02
3     0
4     0
5     0.12
6     0
7     0
8     0
9     0.91
10    0
11    0
12    0
13    1.13
```

How can I do this in R?

Comment: May I just say that I really like this thread for all the different ways people showed to tackle the problem?

Comment: I think it could be worth linking this question (with heaps of very nice answers!) to a similar question based on grouped data: [Fastest way to add rows for missing values in a data.frame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438969/fastest-way-to-add-rows-for-missing-values-in-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 9):

```
library(tidyr)

complete(d, col1 = 1:13, fill = list(col2 = 0))
```

or

```
complete(d, col1 = seq(max(col1))), fill = list(col2 = 0))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 13 × 2
>     col1  col2
>    <int> <dbl>
> 1      1  0.00
> 2      2  0.02
> 3      3  0.00
> 4      4  0.00
> 5      5  0.12
> 6      6  0.00
> 7      7  0.00
> 8      8  0.00
> 9      9  0.91
> 10    10  0.00
> 11    11  0.00
> 12    12  0.00
> 13    13  1.13
> ```

or

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(data.frame(col1 = seq(max(d$col1)))), d)
```

But this will leave `NA`s instead of zeros.

Answer (score 8):

Just for completeness, a self binary join using `data.table` (you will get `NA`s instead of zeroes, but that could be easily changed if needed)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[.(seq(max(col1))), on = .(col1)]
#     col1 col2
#  1:    1   NA
#  2:    2 0.02
#  3:    3   NA
#  4:    4   NA
#  5:    5 0.12
#  6:    6   NA
#  7:    7   NA
#  8:    8   NA
#  9:    9 0.91
# 10:   10   NA
# 11:   11   NA
# 12:   12   NA
# 13:   13 1.13
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way would be the following. Your data is called `mydf` here. You create a data frame with a column including 1 to the max value of `col1`. Then, you use assign the values of `col2` in `mydf` to a new column called `col2` in `foo`. You use the numbers in `col1` in `mydf` as index when you do this process. By this time, you have `NA` in `col2` in `foo`. You want to change NA to 0. So the final step is to do this. You look for NA's position in `col2` in `foo` using `is.na()` and assign zeros to the positions.

```
foo <- data.frame(col1 = 1:max(mydf$col1))
foo$col2[mydf$col1] <- mydf$col2
foo$col2[is.na(foo$col2)] <- 0
```

Taking lmo's idea into an account, you can create a data frame with 0 first and avoid the 3rd step.

```
foo <- data.frame(col1 = 1:max(mydf$col1), col2 = 0)
foo$col2[mydf$col1] <- mydf$col2


#   col1 col2
#1     1 0.00
#2     2 0.02
#3     3 0.00
#4     4 0.00
#5     5 0.12
#6     6 0.00
#7     7 0.00
#8     8 0.00
#9     9 0.91
#10   10 0.00
#11   11 0.00
#12   12 0.00
#13   13 1.13
```

DATA

```
mydf <- structure(list(col1 = c(2L, 5L, 9L, 13L), col2 = c(0.02, 0.12, 
0.91, 1.13)), .Names = c("col1", "col2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: or `foo <- data.frame(col1 = 1:max(mydf$col1), col2=0)` in first line. So you don't have to do the third line.

Comment: @Imo  Yeah that is true. Let me revise my post. Thanks.

Comment: @jazzurro I think your original solution generalizes better for more columns. For instance, if there are 10 columns in the original data set, you could do `foo[names(mydf)[-1]][mydf$col1] <-  mydf[-1]` or something similar (untested). Then changing all zeroes at ones is pretty straightforward too.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks for that feed back. :)

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a different point of view, consider that what you have can be seen as a sparse vector, i.e. a vector whose only the non-zero values are defined. Sparse vectors are implemented by the `Matrix` package in R. If `df` is your initial `data.frame`, try:

```
require(Matrix)
data.frame(col1=seq_len(max(df$col1)),
      col2=as.vector(sparseVector(df$col2,df$col1,max(df$col1))))
#   col1 col2
#1     1 0.00
#2     2 0.02
#3     3 0.00
#4     4 0.00
#5     5 0.12
#6     6 0.00
#7     7 0.00
#8     8 0.00
#9     9 0.91
#10   10 0.00
#11   11 0.00
#12   12 0.00
#13   13 1.13
```

The same result in a one-liner `base` R:

```
data.frame(col1=seq_len(max(df$col1)),
   col2=`[<-`(numeric(max(df$col1)),df$col1,df$col2))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a function that uses `expandRows` from `splitstackshape` package,

```
expand_seq <- function(x){
  x$new <- c(x$col1[1], diff(x$col1))
  new_df <- splitstackshape::expandRows(x, 'new')
  new_df$col1 <- seq(max(new_df$col1))
  new_df$col2[!new_df$col1 %in% x$col1] <- 0
  rownames(new_df) <- NULL
  return(new_df)
}

expand_seq(df)
#   col1 col2
#1     1 0.00
#2     2 0.02
#3     3 0.00
#4     4 0.00
#5     5 0.12
#6     6 0.00
#7     7 0.00
#8     8 0.00
#9     9 0.91
#10   10 0.00
#11   11 0.00
#12   12 0.00
#13   13 1.13
```

Comment: A new function that you can propose for the package? :)

Comment: @jazzurro Sure. It would be really helpful :)

Comment: You can ask Ananda if he is keen.

Answer (score 2):

There are already some interesting answers here.

Just to hop in, we can create a sequence of numbers from 1 to `max(col1)` and then get the respective value of `col2` using `match`

```
col1 = seq(1, max(df$col1))
data.frame(col1, col2 = df$col2[match(col1, df$col1)])

#   col1 col2
#1     1   NA
#2     2 0.02
#3     3   NA
#4     4   NA
#5     5 0.12
#6     6   NA
#7     7   NA
#8     8   NA
#9     9 0.91
#10   10   NA
#11   11   NA
#12   12   NA 
#13   13 1.13
```

This will give `NA`s instead of 0. If we need 0's,

```
data.frame(col1,col2 = ifelse(is.na(match(col1,df$col1)), 0,
                                             df$col2[match(col1,df$col1)]))

#   col1 col2
#1     1 0.00
#2     2 0.02
#3     3 0.00
#4     4 0.00
#5     5 0.12
#6     6 0.00
#7     7 0.00
#8     8 0.00
#9     9 0.91
#10   10 0.00
#11   11 0.00
#12   12 0.00
#13   13 1.13
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `base R` with `merge` and `replace`

```
transform(merge(data.frame(col1= 1:13), df, all.x=TRUE),
                      col2 = replace(col2, is.na(col2), 0))
#    col1 col2
#1     1 0.00
#2     2 0.02
#3     3 0.00  
#4     4 0.00
#5     5 0.12
#6     6 0.00
#7     7 0.00
#8     8 0.00
#9     9 0.91
#10   10 0.00
#11   11 0.00
#12   12 0.00
#13   13 1.13
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see a simple `merge` solution, so here is one:

```
res <- merge(data.frame(col1=1:max(df$col1)),df,by="col1",all.x=TRUE)
res$col2 <- ifelse(is.na(res$col2),0,res$col2)
```

The second line is replacing the `NA`'s from the `merge` (left outer join) with zeros. As @Axeman points out, this can also be accomplished by:

```
res$col2[is.na(res$col2)] <- 0
```

The result is:

```
res
##   col1 col2
##1     1 0.00
##2     2 0.02
##3     3 0.00
##4     4 0.00
##5     5 0.12
##6     6 0.00
##7     7 0.00
##8     8 0.00
##9     9 0.91
##10   10 0.00
##11   11 0.00
##12   12 0.00
##13   13 1.13
```

Comment: Second line can be `res$col2[is.na(res$col2)] <- 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be:

```
for (i in 1:max(test$col1)) {
  if(!(i %in% test$col1)) (test <- rbind(test, c(i, 0)))
}
test <- test[order(test$col1),]
```

Axeman's answer is really sweet, though.

Edit: Data used --

```
test <- structure(list(col1 = c(2, 5, 9, 13), col2 = c(0.02, 0.12, 0.91, 
1.13)), .Names = c("col1", "col2"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

DISCLAIMER: This should really not be used for big datasets. I tried it with 1k rows and it was done in a heartbeat, but my second test with 100k rows is running for minutes now, which really emphasizes Axeman's concerns in his comment.

Comment: In case performance matters, a loop with a in which you grow an object is pretty much worst case scenario. A vectorized solution is much better.

Comment: Yep, I agree with that. The OP stated `my data is`, therefore I did not really think about computing time. // Edit: For funs and giggles, I just ran the code with 100k rows... let's just say it is still running...